# Ошибка сегментирования (С++)

Tags: c++

При запуске файла возникает ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск). Читал, что это может быть из-за того, что происходит утечка памяти, вчитывался в код, но никак не могу найти. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

const char* fileName = "URL-addresses.txt";

bool checkCorrect(char *str)
{
    char *comprStr = new char[7];
    strncpy(comprStr, str, 7);

    if (!strcmp(comprStr,"http://"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

bool searchContact(char* str)
{
    char* tempLink = new char[30];
    ifstream in(fileName);
    if (!in.is_open())  return 0;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >> tempLink;
        if (strcmp(str, tempLink) == 0) return true;
        if (in.eof()) break;
    }
    in.close();
    return false;
}

void download(char* str) {
    system("clear");

    ofstream out(fileName, ios_base::app);
    if (!out.is_open())  exit(1);
    out <<"\n" << str;
    out.close();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    initscr();

    if (!checkCorrect(argv[1]))
    {
        return 2;
    }

    if (!searchContact(argv[1])) {
        return 3;
    }

    switch (atoi(argv[2])) {
        case 1: {
            download(argv[1]);
            endwin();
            return 3;
        }

        case 2: {
            download(argv[1]);
            endwin();
            return 3;
        }

        default: {
            endwin();
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Сразу после `strncpy` у вас идет `strcmp`:

  ```
  strncpy(comprStr, str, 7);

  if (!strcmp(comprStr,"http://"))
    ...
  ```

  Но функция `strncpy` не предназначается и никогда не предназначалась для "безопасного" копирования строк. Если вам таки приспичило использовать ее для этой цели, то не забывайте, что эта функция в общем случае не завершает скопированные данные символом `'\0'`. Сделать это после `strncpy` - ваша обязанность.
- Вас, очевидно, интересует строка длины 7. Для строки длины 7 нужно 8 байтов памяти. Восемь, а не семь. Причем выделять эту память через `new []` нет никакой необходимости

  ```
  char comprStr[8];
  strncpy(comprStr, str, 8);
  comprStr[7] = '\0';

  if (!strcmp(comprStr, "http://"))
    ...
  ```
- Для того, чтобы проверить, не начинается ли строка с `"http://"` совсем не обязательно копировать ее начало в отдельную строку. Если функция `strncmp`, которая это проверит без лишних копирований

  ```
  bool checkCorrect(const char *str)
  {
    return strncmp(str, "http://", 7) == 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: `char *comprStr = new char;

 strcpy(comprStr, str);

 comprStr[7] ='\0';
`  
сделал так, не помогло, c strncpy такая же история

Comment: @Антон Юревич: Это еще что за чушь? Было лучше. `сhar *comprStr = new char[8]; strncpy(comprStr, str, 8); comprStr[7] = '\0';` Только к чему тут вообще `new` приплелось??? `сhar comprStr[8]; strncpy(comprStr, str, 8); comprStr[7] = '\0';`

Comment: Всё так же ошибка сегментирования

Comment: @Антон Юревич: В вашем коде, я думаю, еще хватает ошибоке...

Comment: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
                                                    __strncmp_sse42 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S:198
198 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S: Нет такого файла или каталога.` 
Теперь словил такую информацию в gdb, думаю уже проще работать, но всё равно не знаю что с этим делать

Comment: @Антон Юревич: Я не знаю, какую версию кода вы там сейчас запускаете. И еще раз: в каком месте *вашего* кода происходит падение?

Comment: на функции checkCorrect

Comment: @Антон Юревич: Какую версию кода вы там сейчас запускаете?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка сегментации возникает не при утечке памяти, а при обращении к тому участку памяти, к которому к вас нет доступа.

Вот, почитайте об этом в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).